# JavaScript : not reading entire string in case of very long string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a very long JSONstring of 269313 characters which is stored as a JavaScript variable in a separate js file.

say in CategorisationTree_HNB7x.js

```
jsonMenuData = '[{"mopId":"AUDIT","mopType":"M","exeName":"","inputFileName":"","menuDesc":"Finacle Audit Menu","menus":{}},....
```

I am importing this js file to my html page

```
<script src="../categorisedData/CategorisationTree_HNB7x.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //creating menu elements
        console.log(jsonMenuData.length);
    });
</script>
```

When i try to print the length of this string, in console log, it is showing as 267921 characters only. Last 1392 characters seems to be missing from the string variable.
It doesn't matter how large the string, always somewhere around last 1000 characters are missing.

What am i missing here. How to handle this issue?

Comment: It looks like it should just be a string containing json that is not parsed at that point.  Make sure there isn't an unescaped single quote in the string.  Given that you know how many characters are missing it should give you an idea of where to look for one.

Comment: OP, are there any console errors?

Comment: Is there a chance that the difference comes from escaped characters? IE: `"\n"` or `"\t"` is two characters in the string literal, but when javascript interprets it, it becomes a newline/tab (one character), leading to the difference?

Comment: Valid point.  The OP could try parsing the json and see if any records are actually missing.

Comment: @rmlan - there is no console errors.

Comment: As CRice mentioned, there can be reasons the length differs and the string is still complete, so instead of checking its length, access some of the _missing_ data and see if its there.

Comment: As @CRice mentioned, there where some junk characters in the Json string like "\u003d". I have replaced all the non alphanumeric characters to null while generating the json string. Now string length is matching and i am able to parse the JSON as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the exact problem since I cannot see the your problem string to test but JS uses UTF-16 for its strings and byte length is different than .length

Example :

```
//JS String Lengths

"A".length // -> 1
"Ç".length // -> 1
"".length // -> 2

// Byte Lengths

new Blob(["A"]).size; // -> 1  
new Blob(["Ç"]).size; // -> 2
new Blob([""]).size; // -> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

As @CRice mentioned, there where some junk characters in the Json string like "\u003d". I have replaced all the non alphanumeric characters to null while generating the json string. Now string length is matching and i am able to parse the JSON as well.

Thanks everyone for providing the inputs.